# Regex Escaping. Explanation and Example

Tags: c#, regex, escaping

I would like a simple explanation about regex's escaping structure in C#. I've read the MSDN pages but it seems that i cannot write a working     `Regex.Escape()`
Additionally, a working example of escaping "(", ")" and "." characters would be great. For example     `somestring = Regex.Escape("("+"(.*?))");`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx):

> Escapes a minimal set of characters (,\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), #, ^, $, .,
>   and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes. This instructs the regular expression engine to interpret these characters
>   literally rather than as metacharacters.

Which basically means that, in regular expression language, you have some characters which are *special*. These characters include, operators such as `?`, `*`, `.`, `+`, etc.

To have a regular expression threat for instance, the `+` as the character `+`, and not the *one or more of the previous* operator, we escape it like so: `\+`. This tells the parsing engine to treat the `+` as is.

What the escape method does is that it adds the extra backslash to these characters.

Thus, given this: `Regex.Escape("("+"(.*?))");`, the output string would be `\(\(\.\*\?\)\)`, which would mean, match the given string: `(.*?))`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Can you also provide me an example of escaping (, ) and . in a string. For example string ' s = "Some (text)." '

Comment: @user3640195: That should be covered in the last part of my answer.

Comment: so 's = Regex.Escape(@"\(\)\.");' would provide me a string ' s = Some text '? Or do i have to follow somekind of pattern?

Comment: `Regex.Escape(@"()\.") will yield: \(\)\\\.. `\(` and `\)` because you are escaping `(` and `)` respectively. Then you get \\ because you need to escape the `\` and finally, you get `\.` because you need to escape `.`.

Answer (score 0):

There may some possibilities of regex meta characters present in a variable in which you're trying to use the value of that variable as a regex to search for a particular substring. In this case , we need to put the variable inside the `Regex.Escape` function in-order to make special characters present inside the variable to get automatically escaped.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Regex.Escape("("+"(.*?))")
> ```

Essentially any meta-character in the input gets a backslash in front of it. So:

```
\(\(\.\*\?\)\)
```

But of course, anything that shows the string as if it were in C# source code (like the VS debugger tool windows) will itself escape the backslashes, hence a display something like:

```
\\(\\(\\.\\*\\?\\)\\)
```

(Hence why verbastin strings are so useful with regexes.)

PS. Do not write your own `Regex.Escape`: you'll just miss some edge cases of the syntax (and there are lots). The Framework method is there to use, so use it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. After some tests i realized that Regex.Escape automatically escapes the special characters inside the given string.